# Time Series Analysis in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, analytics

I have a workbook with up to 103 sheets.

- 101 sheets will have a different product volume for Time Series Analysis.
- There is a RAW data tab from which each sheet will pull through the initial volume data.
- There is a summary sheet which is formulated to pull through 12 month forecast for all 101 items.

I want to loop from Sheet 3 to 103 and automate the data analysis, regression part of Time Series Analysis to get the time series data refreshed onto the summary sheet.

I have created a code below to show what I have tried. The issue I am getting is:

- I have to click "Yes" to overwriting the previous regression data which is in range $S$33 in each sheet. I thought that Application.DisplayAlerts = False would fix that.
- Each month the ranges will change. It will always start at $L$2 and $C$2 however needs to run down to the previous month. (Please see highlighted below) we are in Jun-19 now so it needs to range from $L$2 to $L$43 and $C$2 to $C$43 as Line 43 is the line of May-19.

```vb
 Sub TSA ()

    '
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '
    Sheets("SPCS000052").Activate
         Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$L$2:$L$42"), _
            ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$C$42"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range("$S$33") _
            , False, False, False, False, , False

    Sheets("SPCS000053").Activate
         Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$L$2:$L$42"), _
            ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$C$42"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range("$S$33") _
            , False, False, False, False, , False

    Sheets("SPCS000130").Activate
         Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$L$2:$L$42"), _
            ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$C$42"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range("$S$33") _
            , False, False, False, False, , False

    Sheets("SPCS000078").Activate
         Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$L$2:$L$42"), _
            ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$C$42"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range("$S$33") _
            , False, False, False, False, , False

    Sheets("SPCS000063").Activate
         Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$L$2:$L$42"), _
            ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$C$42"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range("$S$33") _
            , False, False, False, False, , False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is `Regress` supposed to do? As for the alerts, if I'm not wrong, that function (Regress) should have an alerts supress as well in order to not get any. If you can paste the content of that function here as well, or at least the top bit, to see what parameters are expected. Also, in the loop... all you want to achieve is to run that command? Last question... Are your sheet names all `SPCS0000XX` ? Starting at `SPCS000001` ending at `SPCS000101` ? Or what are the 2 sheet names to exclude.

Comment: @DarXyde "Regress" is Linnear Regression function in the Data Analysis Toolpack. In terms of the loop I just want to go from Sheet3 to Sheet103, the names of the sheets are not a specific order or order in their name. The 2 sheets to exclude perhaps more simply are "Data" and "Summary" I did try DIM XRange and Range, Dim YRange as Range and Dim ORange as Range, and setting them but it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ranges can be set programatically and you can refer to them with a variable instead of Activesheet. You can use a loop in which you can assemble the name of the sheet. So I'd do something like this:

```
    Dim iLastRow as Long, i As Long
    Dim rC as Range, rL as Range, rS as Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For i = 3 to 101
        sSheetName = "SPCS" & Format(i, "000000")
        Set sh = Sheets(sSheetName)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then      ' check success
            Debug.Print "Error with sheet " & sSheetName
        Else
            iLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rL = Range(sh.Cells(2, 12), sh.Cells(iLastRow, 12)  ' L column
            Set rC = Range(sh.Cells(2, 3), sh.Cells(iLastRow, 3)    ' C column
            Set rS = Range(sh.Cells(2, 19), sh.Cells(iLastRow, 19)   ' S column

            Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", rL, rC, False, True, , _
                     rS, _False, False, False, False, , False
        End If
    Next
```

This is just a simple hint. You'll need to add quite a few more lines to make it robust like checking iLastRow for 0 or success of `Set rX` but for the first try it will do. For the alert I think others have already hit this issue, see this: [suppress-overwrite-existing-data-alert-in-vba-macro](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/84268-suppress-overwrite-existing-data-alert-in-vba-macro) ATPVBAEM looks ignoring/overwriting `DisplayAlert` setting.

EDIT: finding last row is corrected, thanx @ja72

Comment: Wouldn't the last row be found with `.End(xlDown).Row` instead of `.End(xlUp).Row`?

Comment: @ja72 nope, xlUP is better (starting from rows.count, which is all rows in the sheet).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't had time to answer earlier... this is another way to do it:

```vb
Sub TSA()

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook, or Workbooks("book name")
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range


For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    'Alternatively: If ws.Name <> "Data" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

    If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "SPCS" Then
        With ws
            Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", _
                            .Range(rng.Offset(0, 9)), _
                            .Range(rng), _
                            False, _
                            True, _
                            , _
                            .Range("$S$33") '_
                            ', False, False, False, False, , False

        'Since most of the parameters are optional, and last ones you are only passing false values, you can ditch them.
            'uncomment them above if you get any weird results because a false value was actually required
        End With
    End If
Next ws

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Sadly that message box is built in the AddIn itself, and even if you have the password to the AddIn (`Wildebeest!!`), given the actual function is stored in `ANALYS32.XLL` file), you won't be able to do much about it.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. My only question from that is can there be anything done in terms of the variable ranges? The range will change every month. So this month it will be .Range($L$2:$L$43) and .Range($L$2:$L$43). The range is taken from column F. It needs to go down from row 2, to the row that displays last month but come January 2020 it will go back to row 39.

Comment: Assuming `"$S$33"` is always the same, see the updated answer to take in consideration possible different number of rows.